# вставить сепаратор в строку по маске

Tags: php, строки, separator

буду признателен за другой возможный вариант этого кода:

```
<?php
$ISDevID = 'D824BDBA69D7';
$ISPoolID = sprintf("%s.%s.%s",
    substr($ISDevID, 0, 4),
    substr($ISDevID, 5, 4),
    substr($ISDevID, 8, 4),
);
echo $ISPoolID;
```

$ISDevID достается из массива через foreach, заносится в другой массив, из которого уже в виде D824.BDBA.69D7 вытаскивается на сайт

Comment: $ISDevID - всегда 12 символов?

Comment: Да, всегда 12 символов, это MAC адрес

Comment: str_split, chunk_split и т.п.

Comment: Ага, спасибо, буду смотреть ). str_split не подходит, строка должна остаться строкой, а chunk_split то что надо!

Comment: *str_split не подходит, строка должна остаться строкой* Ну так потом implode же...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще вариант:

```
$ISDevID = 'D824BDBA69D7';
echo implode('.', str_split($ISDevID, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов разбить регуляркой на 3 группы по 4 символа.

```
$string = 'D824BDBA69D7';
$pattern = '/^(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})/i';
$replacement = '$1.$2.$3';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); //D824.BDBA.69D7
```

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно подсказали выше:

```
$ISDevID = 'D824BDBA69D7';
$ISPoolID = substr(chunk_split($ISDevID, 4,'.'), 0, -1);
```

Если не использовать substr ...... ,0,-1 появляется точка (в моем случае) в конце форматируемой строки

Comment: *Если не использовать substr ...... ,0,-1 появляется точка (в моем случае) в конце форматируемой строки* И про существование trim() ты тоже не слышал, что ли?

Comment: Слышал ))... Да! спасибо, что напомнили. Это подойдет конечно!